# Can i setup a VM in ESXI with bridging two of it's ethernet adapters?

Tags: vmware-esxi, bridge, adapter, promiscuous

I need to setup a virtual machine running windows server 2012 r2 (with 2 ethernet adapters) and install a firewall software to work in bridge mode ... Is it possible to do this in VMware ESXi using promiscuous option?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are asking is that you want to setup a firewall on a Windows 2012r2 server. Yes, you can set it up on ESXi. You just need to have the two network adapters on two different network subnets or vlans.

The traffic traversing one network to the other would be ruled by the firewall.

Promiscuous is not needed for a firewall. It is needed if you are doing network sniffing or some type of intrusion detection system like snort.

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1002934